# Set position in Bootstrap without affecting responsiveness

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am a noob in web design. I have just begun experimenting with Bootstrap. I want to add two buttons
[like this,](https://ibb.co/tzjt27t)

but, I am getting [this](https://ibb.co/frdsQbF) on mobile devices

with this code:

```
 <button style = "position:absolute; left:38%; top:50%; z-index=0" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
 <button style = "position:absolute; left:53%; top:50%; z-index:0" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
```

I know I shouldn't add position attributes as they make responsiveness ineffective, but not using them places the buttons [like this](https://ibb.co/2yqwGfJ).

So how should I go about it? How can I specify position without affecting responsiveness?

Thank You!

Comment: Put the buttons in a wrapping div, and give the div `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`, then set it as a flex box with this styles: `display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center` and give the buttons any left or right margin to create space between them. Remove the current postioning absolute styling also

Comment: @zgood watch out, you have a typo in justify-content. I'm no grammar nazi but since he says he's a noob I don't want him to copy the code with a mistake in it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @zgood, I have it fixed with this:

```
 <div style="width:100vw; height: 100vh; display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content:center">
        <button style="margin:20px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
        <button style="margin:20px" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large button</button>
 </div>
```